# what is その効力 in this context?

Tags: reading-comprehension

super popular dude XXX disapears, start of an epilogue

> 数週間後。
>
> 大学構内からXXXの姿が消え、彼に好意を寄せていた女性たちが騒動となったのは一週間ほど前のことである。
>
> いまでは長期の休学だとか外国の大学へ編入しただとか、ありそうも無いような噂が飛び交ってこそいるものの、失踪直後ほどは騒がれなくなった。
>
> **偶像というものは皆の目にとまっているからこそ崇拝できるのであり、目前からなくなってしまえば意外とその効力が無くなるのも早い。**
>
> ‥‥そういうものだ。

A testament to Xxx's lasting impact would be the worshiping of XXX from all the attention  this has gotten; and that if he disappeared before our eyes,  it would be premature to say that it would be surprisingly become ineffective.

totally lost when it comes to the 3rd sentence here, i don't think it is refering to any specific thing prior to the epilogue, but i may be mistaken.

Thank for clarifying

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would be helpful to know which part of the sentence you are having trouble with specifically and why you add things like 'a testament', 'Xxx', 'premature', 'attention this has gotten', and 'ineffective', which don't appear in the Japanese.

I would translate it slightly paraphrased as:

> 'An 'idol' is worshipped/adored ***because*** it is plainly visible
>   to all, and if it disappears from sight that effect dissipates
>   especially quickly.'

Highly paraphrased:

> 'Even the most popular boy, taken out of the mix for long enough, will
>   be quickly forgotten.'

Comment: Hm, I suppose the emphasis on just how popular this dude through the story caused me to be very biased in terms of how I approached this. Based on what you wrote, it wasn't entirely clear for me that 皆の目にとまっている was referring a general idea and not the present situation

Comment: @charu While the sentence relates to the situation surrounding character Xxx, it does not mention him at all. It is presented as an abstract but pertinent 'expression' or 'saying'.